# Using Bundler's rake release with git-flow

Tags: rubygems, bundler, git-flow

I'm using git-flow for the development, and Bundler to release my gem.  My question is how to use both git-flow release and rake release together.  Both tag git, and since the tag is the same there is a conflict.

How should I handle this without having to delete tags.  Right now I'm on the develop branch (git-flow), and to move it to the master branch using git-flow, you use a git-flow release.

Thanks for your help,

-Damien

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like this workflow does it:

```
git flow release start v0.0.9
...
git flow release finish -n v0.0.9 
git checkout master
rake release
```

The -n command-line argument tells git-flow not to tag the branch, so when you do a rake release, it will be tagged correctly.